# Event callback function out of scope

Tags: javascript, oop, event-handling

I am struggling with events a little bit. I want class A to fire an event and class B shall catch that event and pass the event data to its own method:

```
class ClassA {
    constructor() {
        window.addEventListener("fire", function (e) { this.fired(e.detail); }); //<--- not working
     }

    fired(data) {
        console.log("fired by: "+data);
    }
}

class ClassB {
    constructor() {
        var event = new CustomEvent("fire", { detail: { data: "John Doe" } } );
        window.dispatchEvent(event);
        console.log("fired");
    }
}

new ClassA(); //adds event listener
new ClassB(); //event dispatch
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the scope of this does not refer to the class. You can use an arrow function instead in your ClassA:

```
window.addEventListener("fire", (e) => { this.fired(e.detail); })
```